# Theory,Processes fork()

Tags: c, linux, process

Goodmorning, i would like to ask 2 things..
1) what returns a fork() did on a child which has already a pid==0 ? if i continue to fork on every son, each of them will have 0 as pid ?? or not ?
2) this is my file Buffer.c and it runs on a single process.
At the beginning it forks() out some Producers who produce() and some Consumers who consume() ,but I am afraid that every producers enters in the next for cicle and it starts to produce himself other consumers!! because it write pid=-1 so...
I want that this piece of code produce only P producers and C consumers, but i need to know why every producer do not create other consumers!
Can you help me,maybe giving me a scheme of how many processes i will create with this code?
Maybe doing a scheme as this:

Father:
    8 producers
    -
    - 
    -
    ...
        each of them produces: 5 consumers
etc etc......

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  /....

  pid_t pid;
  pid_t cons_pid[C];


  /* fork producers */
  pid = -1;
  for(i=0; i<P && pid!=0; i++)
    pid=fork();

  switch(pid) {
  case -1:
    ...
  case 0:
    /* GENERIC PRODUCER i */
   ...
    /* PRODUCE() */
    printf("Producer %d exits\n",i);
  ...
    return 0;
  }

  /* fork consumers */
  pid = -1;
  for (j=0; j<C && pid!=0; j++)
    pid = cons_pid[j] = fork();

  switch(pid) {
  case -1:
    ....error
  case 0:
    /* GENERIC CONSUMER j */
    CONSUME()....
    }
    return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Did you do any reading on fork, exec, PID, PPID etc? Homework?

Comment: Can somebody create a HOMEWORK tag please!!!

Comment: Homework-tag is not allowed ;-)

Comment: I read about it, but i am afraid that every producer will also fork() some consumers,right ? do you agree or  not ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what returns a fork() did on a child which has already a pid==0

0 is not a valid PID, hence by definition there can't be an process with PID=0 and thus PID=0 is a perfectly well defined return for indicating child status.

> if i continue to fork on every son, each of them will have 0 as pid

No process ever  has PID=0. All PIDs are greater than zero! A zero is *just* the **return value** received by the newly forked process to indicate that *it's the child*. The actual PID a child process got is queried using the `getpid` function from the child process. However the parent process can't perform such a query, since in the time between `fork` and a assumed query function call, the child may already have terminated (race condition). So you want `fork` to return the PID to the parent directly.

BTW: The terminology is *parent* and *child* not *father* and *son* (processes are things not people, despite what the TRON movies depict).

Regarding your code snippet: A `switch` statement is the wrong choice here. You want to use an `if` statement.

Comment: thank you, but in this case i am afraid that every producer will also fork() some consumers,right ? do you agree or not ?
(this piece of code should be correct, has been made by an expert)

Comment: @user2993592: Well, if the return value of fork is 0, the process is a child process and should refrain from forking anything else. So the 0==fork() path will do something prevents the consumer process fork to happen. In your case it's the return statement within the producer pid==0 branch. That return will terminate the producer process before it reached the consumer forking.

Answer (score 0):

`fork()` splits up the current process into a father and a child.  The child will have a new PID, the father retains the old PID.  In both processes `fork()` returns after the splitting.  In the father the return value will be the PID of the child (to make it known), and in the child the return value will be 0.

Comment: thank you, but in this case i am afraid that every producer will also fork() some consumers,right ? do you agree or not ? (this piece of code should be correct, has been made by an expert)

Answer (score 0):

**1)**  The lowest possible process ID is 1, this is the ID of the init process from which all other processes are forked. Therefore, it is not possible for a child or for your parent process to "already have ID 0". Your child's process ID is *necessarily* greater than 1. Thus, the problem that you are afraid of cannot happen.

**2)**  The confusion that you state is the reason why `fork` (which returns *twice*, once for the parent and once for the newly created child!) has a somewhat "weird" return value which can have so many different values:

- it can be `-1`, then something went wrong, and *no child was created*.
- it can be a positive value, then *you are in the parent process*, and the value is the child's process ID. It's as if you called any other "normal" function that just returned normally.
- it can be `0`, then your code knows it is now running *in the child process*.

You must examine the return value (`if()`) so you know what process you are in. Then no such thing as you decribe can happen (or, should happen, this presumes your code does not have any bugs).

**EDIT:**
The code can be rewritten slightly so it gets rid of the `&& pid!=0` inside the loop and thus looks a bit less scary overall:

```
int main()
{
    int pid, i;
    pid_t cons_pid[C];

    for(int i=0; i<P; ++i)
    {
        pid=fork();
        if(pid == -1) exit(1); /* fork error */
        if(pid ==  0) { producer(); return 0; }
    }
    for(i=0; i<C; ++i)
    {
        pid = fork();
        if(pid == -1) /* fork error */
            { /* should do a kill_producers(); here */ exit(2); }
        else if(pid ==  0) /* consumer */
            { consumer(); return 0; }
        else /* master process, remember all consumer pids */
            { cons_pid[j] = pid; }
    }
    /* ... */
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you, but in this case i am afraid that every producer will also fork() some consumers,right ? do you agree or not ?
(this piece of code should be correct, has been made by an expert)

Comment: The code looks "somewhat weird", but entirely correct, and it should work as intended. It creates `P` child processes that work as producers and exit, a single parent process continues, which then creates `C` child processes again (that work as consumer, and exit). The code would be easier to understand if the `if` clause was in the forking loop, then the loop's test condition would be somewhat easier (no need to break loop for child processes in that case), but functionally that's the same. Producers exit via `return 0;`, so they don't create any consumers.

Comment: The only thing that will maybe not work as intended is storing the consumer pids. I'm not sure what you want to achieve, but as it is, you store the pid for every consumer in an array for the parent process, and also partially in the arrays owned by the consumers. You probably only use them in the parent process. See edit.

Comment: thank youuuuu yesss!! i noticed the return !! so no problem !!